# c# xmlnode select single node to remove

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xml-documentation

I have an XML document that has nodes/values like this:

```
<data name="btnAutoTrans" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Auto Trans</value>
</data>
<data name="btnDieEngine" xml:space="preserve">
 <value>Diesel Engine</value>
</data>
```

I need to select a single node for a specific name="btnDieEngine" (for example)

but all the code I have tried from searching google always returns NULL value.

The original code I had was

```
XmlNode node = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("data[name='btnDieEngine']");
```

but this returns null.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: have you tried something like this `Brad` 
`SelectSingleNode("//data[@name='btnDieEngine']").InnerText;`

Comment: Is there any reason that you aren't using [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)?

Comment: No reason, I was just using xmldoc for all the other processing I was doing and it works fine that way.

Can you provide an example of the xDocument?

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is invalid. Try that one:

```
XmlNode node = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("data[@name='btnDieEngine']");
```

Comment: That didnt work but if I used:

    xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//data[@name='btnDieEngine']");

it kinda worked but gave me this:
{element, Name="data"}

vs the exact value I wanted and in VS it has drop down with a lot of values in it.

If I search for all the data and I search for OuterXML it returns the value I need, but I am unsure how to get this value into a variable so that I can do something similar to 

node.RemoveAll()

For that specific node name